# Is refresh in Elasticsearch atomic?

Tags: elasticsearch

Scenario: I have my index refresh interval set to -1 (no automatic refresh). I add 20 documents to index using bulk with refresh=true. Are all documents visible at same time? The question is are Elasticsearch refreshes atomic? Are all the changes made to index since last refresh visible all at once?

Answer (score 1):

As Elasticsearch is distributed, it is considered as eventually consistent - meaning that (on some operations) after some time they would be consistent through all calls. The reason is that the data is spread between multiple replicas of the same shard, and search/get requests might be routed to different nodes, where the shards might be still synching with new changes, and therefore some searches might return data which is not the latest.

Comment: In addition to the existing answer, if you are looking to have all documents immediately visible upon refresh, you should use the `refresh=wait_for` parameter.

Comment: So then `refresh=true` means the refreshing will start after the call to `index` returns and `refresh=wait_for` means that refreshing will complete before the call to `index` returns? In other words, `refresh=true` means eventual consistency but `refresh=wait_for` means strong consistency?